# Can MobileFirst be used for Web application

Tags: web-applications, ibm-mobilefirst

We are using MobileFirst as the platform for building a hybrid application .I know that we can use mobileFirst technology for building 
hybrid applications for iPhone, iPad, Android, WIndows Phone etc. In addition to these platforms we need a web version also. I was wondering what is the 
best practice for developing the application which supports mobile platforms Plus web application

Specifically 
   In Mobile First Console,  "Preview as common resources" - is giving a web page version of the same hybrid app we develop. Is this web page is good enough to be used as a web application. Is there any best practices used in this typical scenario

Another approach is to have mobilefirst app serve for hybrid app , webapp  will be developed as a separate app - possibly making use of the same backend components
   written for the hybrid application

Please give me a direction

Answer (score 0):

In your question you have mentioned the mobile environments that you can add to your project. In addition to those you can also add:

- Mobile Web: intended to be displayed in the mobile browser application of a smartphone (Chrome, Mobile Safari, etc)
- Desktop Browser: intended to be displayed in a desktop browser application running on a Desktop machine (OS X, Linux, Windows, etc...)

It sounds like you should be exploring the second option; adding to your application the Desktop Browser environment.

The product of that environment is a link that you can obtain from the MobileFirst Console. You can then either embed it inside an existing website that you serve from some server of your own, and use it as-is.

Comment: Desktop Browser : - will it still be a single page application  calling services with Javascript and updating the UI. ?
Also In web we need much better UI and contents - So even when we use responsive web design to detect devices and render - we will still end up in heavy html pages which will hide the unwanted stuff in small devices. ?

Comment: Yes, it will need to be a SPA, but like with mobile, you can use any UI framework you want.